# How to only update/redraw one component at a time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I have a screen with some cards. On the bottom of the screen is a button, where I can execute some functions once user pressed the button. What I did was making a function that updates the hook called "modalOpen". Thus, whenever the button is pressed, it set the modalOpen to true using hook and a modal sheet is displayed.

This works fine until I realize that every time I open the modal sheet, all my other hooks are being triggered. Thus, all my cards are constantly redraw whenever I click on the button.

I have tried few methods, I initially tried setting my conditions for my useEffect, which called a setCards hook inside, but for some reason this seems to fail.

I have tried creating a separate component for my modal sheet, but the problem is on how to pass the hook to my main app screen so I can trigger it by pressing the button. I used reference to no avail as well as passing the props back to main app screen.

Is my goal correct? What should I do to achieve this?

Comment: This is one the difficult things to achieve in react.  React has a serious performance and rendering issue.  I have build many apps in react.  The best way to achieve this "selective rendering" is to have global state like a Redux store then your Function components will bind to the values in the store.  Also take into account that qhen the parent renders all the children components will re-execute.

Comment: Also avoid passing properties from parent to children. It is better that each component "knows" how to bind to its own properties.